# Linux: How to eval the contents of STDOUT?

Tags: linux, bash, sh, tcsh

Consider you have a file with some sort of terminal command.  How might each line be executed?  Can you pipe the output of more into an `eval`?

```
%> more ./foo.txt
```

Edit:

After some help/guidance from the comments, I think I should also make note that it's been a while since I've done any shell scripting, so while I say `eval` I may mean `echo` or some other way of executing code.

If foo.txt contains various lines of code, but I want to execute the line that contains `echo 'bar bar'`, I'm looking for a way to do that from, let's say a `grep`.  Something logically similar to:

```
grep echo foo.txt | xargs echo
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just need to evaluate every line of a file, you don't need a complicated `eval` or `stdout` redirection. Two easy options:

- Source the file (`source filename.sh` or `. filename.sh`).
- Make the file executable and run it (`chmod +x filename.sh; ./filename.sh`)

If you really need to `eval` each line of a file in a loop, [do it with `while`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do eval "$line"; done < filename.sh
```

You can also pipe the output of any command to `while`:

```
grep foo filename.sh | while IFS= read -r line; do eval "$line"; done
```

If you need to pass something to `source` (or `.`), which expects a file name as an argument, you can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```
source <( grep foo filename.sh )
```

Comment: I like, but is there a way to do this w/o using `bash`?  I know I tagged it, so I'm just curious, since I don't always use it.

Comment: `source` isn't Bash-specific and should work in most other shells (Bourne Shell, (t)csh) as well.

Comment: Right now, `source` would work but I like to think ahead in the case that there are lines I wan't to strip out and possibly use the output of `grep`

Comment: Technically, `source` is a non-standard synonym for `.`.

Comment: @chepner: right, but can you pump `more`/`grep` into an `eval` (guessing `echo`) from the terminal command line? Perhaps into `find -exec`?

Comment: @vol7ron: You cannot pipe into `eval`, since it does not read from standard input. It takes a string as an argument. That said, why do you think you need to use `eval`? It's rarely necessary.

Comment: @chepner not saying I do - been a while since I've done any shell scripting. I may need to edit the question, instead of posting this as a comment, but I'm looking to execute specific lines from a file (eg output of `grep string_match foo.txt`) I figured I'd have to pipe that into `echo` or `eval`

Comment: @vol7ron You can use process substitution to pass the output of a list of commands to `source`, or pipe the output from your scripts to `while`.

Comment: @slhck don't get me wrong the `while` worked in Bash, I was looking for something that may be shell independent, which again, I asked too open of a question so it's entirely my fault.  The `source` I think would work, just isn't as descriptive when I go back to read what I did a couple years from now :)

Comment: @vol7ron `while` for reading each line and process substitution is also supported in Zsh and ksh. You can use `while` in the Bourne Shell as well, so this is as portable as you can get AFAIK. (t)csh uses completely different syntax, so you won't get far with that I'm afraid.

Comment: @slhck and that's the rub :(

Comment: @vol7ron Not pretty, but you can always use a temporary file and source that of course.

Comment: @slhck thanks for continuing to think on this, I'd rather force the use of `bash` than to go that route, but it's an interesting idea.